# CAN Protocol stacks for linux

Tags: can-bus

Can anybody suggest me the list of CAN Protocol stacks for linux?? I am using freescale imx286 processor which supports CAN Bus and I am using Flex CAN driver. On top of this i have to use one CAN protocal stack like CANOpen.

Answer (score 3):

if you run Linux and are using one of the LINUX CAN drivers like can4linux or SocketCAN, both are available for the i.MX family with FlexCAN, than you can select between different manufacturers of CANopen and/or J1939 protocol stacks.
Please look at the [CAN-Wiki](http://www.can-wiki.info/doku.php?id=can_higher_layer_protocols:main) for an overview of available products.
CAN in Automation (CiA) offers a product guide.
I can recommend looking at [emtas](http://www.emtas.de/en/produkte/canopen-slave-stack), offering protocol stacks and development tools.

Comment: Also take a look at this [CAN wiki on elinux.org](http://elinux.org/index.php?title=CAN_Bus).

Comment: Thanks hjoe and yegorich for your reply,

Comment: I downloaded CANOpenNode source from git, I gone through that code, they are using rt calls, is it really required rt calls in CANOpen stack?? is there any link to download Non-rt CANOpen stack for Linux (iMX286)??

Comment: If you need real time as always depends on the application. In most cases  a standard Linux kernel is fast and responsible enough.
I can only recommend commercial CANopen stacks. Besides the code, you too will get professional support.